# Security Issue with Nodejs

Tags: node.js, security, xss, yeoman, angular-fullstack

So basically I'm developing an application with the angular-fullstack generator from yeoman.

I ran my server on a digitalocean server to test some stuff and I noticed there's been some weird requests like the ones one the following image:

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aq7O5.png)

I assume this is just someone trying to screw my site, but my question is, is this working?

Is my application not secure? I noticed it's responding with 200's so I'm wondering if the requests went through.

Though when I try to do get requests and emulate what the hacker was trying to do I don't really get any responses.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: looks like your typical vulnerability scanner. Just hits a bunch of commonly known vulnerable routes looking for possible vectors of attack. 200 status code simply means your 404 handler isn't giving a 404 error. I don't think you have anything to worry about as far as this particular crawler. I am curious though as to why /app/main gave a 404 while all the *.php requests gave 200.

Comment: " but my question is, is this working?" --- the request handling crashed with an unhandled exception. How do you think?

Answer (score 0):

- to make sure that your website is secure , the first thing you need to do , is to scan it with any vulnerability scanners.
- any request returns 200 , is OK , but it depends on the response itself , and the behavior of your application .
- you need to identify what is (hacked website) means for you in this application , and based on what you need to secure , you need to monitor and scan it.

Answer (score 0):

Attacking wp-login.php by brute force is very common. One thing you can do is protect it via .htpasswd, there are instructions on how to do it in the [WP Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Brute_Force_Attacks#Password_Protect_wp-login.php). There are some other good suggestions to protect yourself in there as well.